# next.js with typescript fails with unexpected token `?`

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

next.js  `npm run dev`  keeps failing with this optional property in tsx file:

```
Syntax error: Unexpected token

  44 |
  45 | type State<T_HT> = {
> 46 |   ghostHighlight: ?{
     |                   ^
  47 |     position: T_ScaledPosition
  48 |   },
  49 |   isCollapsed: boolean,
```

what causes this, how to resolve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Optional properties, question mark should come before colon as below

```js
ghostHighlight ?: {
  position: T_ScaledPosition
}
```

Comment: thank you so much. I am new to typescript, and I was converting some js to ts

Comment: No problem, good luck at that. Don't forget to mark it as answer if it helped you ;)

Answer (score 1):

Question mark position is wrong here. The question mark should be  like this

```js
      45 | type State<T_HT> = {
    > 46 |   ghostHighlight?: {
      47 |     position: T_ScaledPosition
      48 |   },
      49 |   isCollapsed: boolean,
```